# How to augment one corner of a central composite design in R?

Tags: r

Using the DoE.wrapper package to create a central composite design.  How can I augment one corner of the design?  Essentially I'd like more data for all levels of one factor in the absence of the others.

```
library(DoE.wrapper)

myccd <- ccd.design(nfactors = 3, factor.names = list( dog=c(0,100),cat=c(0,100), turkey=c(0,100)), alpha = 1, ncenter=2)

full factorial design needed
creating full factorial with 8 runs ...

myccd
      Block.ccd dog cat turkey
C1.9          1  50  50     50
C1.7          1   0 100    100
C1.6          1 100   0    100
C1.2          1 100   0      0
C1.1          1   0   0      0
C1.3          1   0 100      0
C1.8          1 100 100    100
C1.5          1   0   0    100
C1.4          1 100 100      0
C1.10         1  50  50     50
S2.7          2  50  50     50
S2.5          2  50  50      0
S2.6          2  50  50    100
S2.8          2  50  50     50
S2.3          2  50   0     50
S2.1          2   0  50     50
S2.2          2 100  50     50
S2.4          2  50 100     50
class=design, type= ccd
```

I want to add two rows/corner points for:

- dog=50,cat=0, turkey=0
- dog=100, cat=0,turkey=0

**Tried so far:**

It is possible to add rows manually to the underlying dataframe within the `design` object, but I'm using `rsm` for the analysis, so the variables will need to be coded, such that it would be much easier if it could be done using a package.

Comment: `rsm` doesn't actually require data to be coded; it just supports coding if it is present. Also, you may use functions like `as.coded.data`, `decode.data`, etc. to reformulate a data.frame with and without whatever codings you want.

Comment: @rvl  That is true...not sure why I'd shackled myself to the DoE... Thanks.